# GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: syntax error in C++ but same syntax works on terminal

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I am creating a video stream from my headless raspberry pi using usb camera and opencv.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Raspi OS: Bullseye

USB Camera

gst syntax test on terminal:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480 ! autovideosink -v
```

In OpenCV C++:

```
string pipeline;
pipeline = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480 ! autovideosink -v";

cv::VideoCapture cap(pipeline, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

When I launch the pipeline from terminal it creates a window with by usb webcam feed. However when I try to use the same pipeline from c++ it throws this error:

```
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (734) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: syntax error
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  cannot predict with an empty OpenCV image
Aborted
```

What am i missing in the syntax in the code?

**Edit:**
After some trials I could get the pipeline generated, with this:

```
pipeline = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480 ! appsink";
```

and warning:

```
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (961) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
```

.
.
.
some stuff for that frame
.
.

```
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (509) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to query pipeline state
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1824) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Could not read from resource.
```

When searched for it, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63091548/gstreamer-warning-cannot-query-video-position-status-0-value-1-duration-1). Which led to a bug report [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10324) and [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/14834).

I am using OpenCV 4.5, and I assume that bug would have been fixed by later version as it was reported for OpenCV 3.4.

Comment: Probably you need a space between `videoconvert` and `!`,  _"videoconvert!"_.

Comment: I made that change, but still same error

Comment: What if you change this v4l2src to v4l2sink?

Comment: @toyotaSupra it throws `instance of 'std::invalid_argument'` with that pipeline

Comment: Did you try this? v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw,width=640,height=480' ! imxv4l2sink

Comment: @toyotaSupra I think this pipeline statement works, but there is some other issue with v4l that is making the frames empty and triggers OpenCV.

Comment: It is not OpenCV problem. It is Bullseye problem. Newer version  12 will be coming in 2023 or 2024.